# Multiple scanfs?

Tags: c, scanf

When l run the program, it asks to enter birth month then when l hit enter it asks to enter the day but when l click enter, it asks again to enter the birth month.

Why does it has multiple scanfs on `getmonth` function? help

```
int getmonth();
int getday();
int zodiacsign(int month, int day);
void zodiacloop();

int main(){
        zodiacloop();
        return;
}

int getmonth(){
    int month;
    printf("\nEnter birth month(1-12): ");
    scanf("%d",&month);
    return month;
}

int getday(){
    int day;
    printf("\nEnter birth day(1-31): ");
    scanf("%d",&day);
    return day;
}

int zodiacsign(int month, int day){
    switch(getmonth()){
        case 1: 
        if(day>=21)
        printf("\nAquarius");
        break;
}
}

void zodiacloop(){
    int months,day;
    months=getmonth();
    day=getday();
    zodiacsign(months,day);
}
```

Comment: Consider `switch(getmonth())` vs `switch(month)`

Comment: ahh i see it now, thank you so much !!

Comment: Note that it is generally best to end format strings with a newline, rather than start them newline and omit the newline at the end.  All else apart, it makes debugging easier — the output appears in a more timely manner when there's a newline at the end to encourage the system to show the data just printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `zodiacloop` function:
in this line `months=getmonth();` you call `getmonth()` for the first time.
After that you call `zodiacsign`, and in  `switch(getmonth())` you call `getmonth()` for the second time.

So the solution is that you should replace `switch(getmonth())` by `switch(month)` in order to avoid calling `getmonth()` two times!